# Select Case Structure

Tags: excel, vba

My question is the following, the following "Select Case", Range is between A1:A100. After I try the following code I only get one result for the 100 progress results I need.  Code Listed below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim score As Integer, result As String
 score = Range("A1").Value

Select Case score
    Case Is >= 80
    result = "very good"
    Case Is >= 70
    result = "good"
    Case Is >= 60
    result = "sufficient"
    Case Else
    result = "insufficient"
End Select

    Range("B1").Value = result

End Sub
```

Comment: You never assign another value to `score`.

Comment: You’ll need to research for loops

Comment: You need to loop over the 100 cells.  Right now your code only looks at A1 and responds in B1.  BTW why vba at all, when a simple INDEX(MATCH()) will do this without the need for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify that you want to perform the same function on every cell in the range you've defined, you can do a `FOR EACH` loop like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim score As range, result As String
 set score = Range("A1:a100")

for each c in score.cells

Select Case c.value
    Case Is >= 80
    result = "very good"
    Case Is >= 70
    result = "good"
    Case Is >= 60
    result = "sufficient"
    Case Else
    result = "insufficient"
End Select

    c.offset(0,1) = result  'specifies the cell 1 column to the right of the current cell

next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do.  It's fairly strait forward using a `For ... Next` loop to cycle through the cells in the column A range listed and then placing the value from the `Select Case` statement in the cell adjacent in column B

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim score As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim xlCell As Range
        For Each xlCell In Range("A1:A100")
            score = xlCell
            Select Case score
                Case Is >= 80
                    result = "very good"
                Case 70 To 79
                    result = "good"
                Case 60 To 69
                    result = "sufficient"
                Case Is < 60
                    result = "insufficient"
            End Select
            xlCell.Offset(0, 1) = result
        Next xlCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you, very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't use a loop here, it's much faster to do it this way than looping a cell at a time:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With Range("B1:B100")
    .Formula = "=IF(A1>79,""very good"",IF(A1>69,""good"",IF(A1>59,""sufficient"",""insufficient"")))"
    .Calculate
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
End Sub
```

It puts a formula in to calculate the results, then it forces a calculate (only needed if calculation is set to manual otherwise you can delete this line), then it copies and pastes back as values.

If this is for a school assignment and you have been told to use a loop or case statement then yes use the statements you were told but otherwise I would advise to avoid looping when you can.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!